# Transform json to javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, object, transform

I'm trying to send a dict from python:

```py
def toJsonCustom(self):

        ajson = []
        ajson.append({
        'id': self.id,
        'data': self.data
        })

        return json.dumps(

            ajson, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__, separators=(',', ':'),indent=4,
        )



async def curl(url,data):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url, json={'datajson':data}) as response:
        print(repr(response))
            chunk = await response.content.read()
            print('Downloaded: %s' % len(chunk))



#output JSON: 

"{"datajson": "[\n    {\n        \"id\":\"test\",\n        \"data\":\"test\"\n    }\n]"}"
```

When trying to convert the output of this **json** into an object from **javascript** I get undefinied.

```
  const data = JSON.parse(get(props, 'websocket.data', null)) || get(state, 'websocket.data') || 'No data';


  console.log('Object json: ', (data));


# output: {"datajson": "[ n    { n         "id ": "test "  n         "data ": "test " n    } n]"}


  console.log('Object json: ', (data.id));

# output:undefined
```

How can I transform the **json** into a **javascript** object in a correct way?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how python logs things but what you have under #output JSON is not json. Also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `data.datajson[0].id`

Comment: Hi @ehacinom , 

I get the following:

TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined.

What is happening?

Comment: when debugging, try do parts at a time. So, first logging out `console.log(data)` is a good idea. next try `console.log('datajson', data.datajson)` (you don't need the parenthesis around the data). if that's undefined, you need to figure out the `typeof` your objects. Try `typeof data`, `typeof data.datajson`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: console.log ('datajson', data.datajson) returns undefined.

And when the json parses again, as @vassiliskrikonis says, I get:

Unexpected token or in JSON at position 0

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` log? what about `console.log(typeof data)`

Comment: console.log (data): {"datajson": "[\ n {\ n \" id \ ": \" test \ ", \ n \" value \ ": \" test \ "\ n} \ n]"}
console.log (typeof data):

     string

     console.log ('datajson', data.datajson):

     datajson undefined

.  It seems that the JSON is well built. I have checked the data output from
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
     I don't understand why I get undefined ...

Comment: So `data` is a string. not an object. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to get the variable `data` into an object.

Comment: that means, `let x = JSON.parse(data)`. then `console.log(typeof x, x)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to parse the JSON string twice to get the object you need:

- the first parse gives you the object `{ "datajson": "[{..." }`, *notice that the value of the `datajson` property is a string*
- so let's parse again the above object `nestedData = JSON.parse(data.datajson)`

Comment: I get: Unexpected token or in JSON at position 0

Comment: As I saw in a comment above, if `data.datajson` returns _undefined_ then the issue is something else entirely. Try making a reproducible script as Jabberwocky commented you so we can help you :)